# Mathematicly Untangeling Untangle.

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, planar-graphs

I have a new addiction, I play Untangle  to often, and i am wondering what is the mathematics behind it.

some free games: (but be warned highly addictive)

Javascript: 
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/untangle.html

Android: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=softkos.untanglemeextreme&hl=en

the rules are simple:

You are given a number of points, some of which have lines drawn between them. You can move the points about arbitrarily; your aim is to position the points so that no line crosses another.

in some versions the difficulty is enriched by making 1 to 3 points unmovable.

This simple puzzle gives rise to all kinds of topological questions:

- is there an algorhitms to solve them?

Some of the games in the android download I was unable to solve, and that makes me wonder, probably there are unsolvable untangle puzzles (so that in any situation some lines will cross)

- how can you recognize them?
- what are the minimal cases of unsolvable puzzles?
- are there fundamentaly different cases of unsolvable puzzles?

Are there any mathematical reports written about these puzzles?

see now back trying to solve one.....

Comment: You may like to read about [planar graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph).

Comment: http://planarity.net/game.html is a another version, the higher levels take a lot of patience.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the mathematics, but the first software you cite (by Simon Tatham) has always generated the puzzles via creating a planar graph and randomly translating its vertices to the locations on a circle --- it cannot generate unsolvable puzzles. It even supplies a "Solve" button.

Comment: It seems that the Android version linked from the question is dead; I recommend https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.boyle.chris.sgtpuzzles which also only generates planar graphs (no unsolvable puzzles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are unsolvable puzzles. Untangle gives you a *graph*, i.e. a set of vertices (points) with edges (lines) between some of them. You are asked to find an embedding of the graph into the two-dimensional plane such that no two edges cross each other. A graph where that is possible is called a *planar* graph.

Not all graphs are planar - the smallest non-planar graph is the graph containing 5 vertices, and edges between *all* pairs of vertices. I.e., you start out with a pentagram, and then draw lines between *all* pairs of corners.

There are various ways to decide whether a graph is planar - check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing

If you read those articles carefully, you'll notice that it doesn't really say that the edges must be *lines* - it allows edges to be any kind of curve. That, however, doesn't really make a difference. If you find some embedding of a graph into the two-dimensional plane where the edges - if represented as arbitrary curves - don't intersect one another, you can always move the points around such that these curves become straight lines.

Comment: The size of a graph is dependent on the amount of edges, so the smallest non-planar graph is actually $K_{3,3}$

Comment: @TimRatigan I went with $K_5$ simply because it was easier to explain what it looks like. But you're right of course that $K_{3,3}$ has fewer edges.

Comment: @TimRatigan That depends a lot on your specific notion of size; for algorithm complexity the canonical notion is arguably $|V|+|E|$, but mathematically most folks seem to enumerate graphs by vertex count first, and only then tally edges and such within a given vertex count.

Comment: @fgp Please review my suggested edit ( which I hope is still visible at URL https://math.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/347732 ) and decide if you think it is an improvement. I think it makes your answer more general since it would then cover software (including the current version of Untangle) which does not generate the graph randomly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The theory of force directed drawing algorithms(further theory of Tutte's barycenter method ) is the way to solve it if is planar...if is not you drop in the previous answer.

BtW cool game :)